# How do I create a bonded VPN to increase available bandwidth on Windows?

Tags: linux, networking, windows-10, vpn, aggregation

I am hoping to create a faster VPN for internet access by combining two or more slower VPNs. As to the reasoning, it's partially the interest and partially because I want to use a datacenter very close to where I live (Phoenix) to minimize latency.

I am running a Windows PC and would be using Linux VPS servers to host my own VPNs. I found a [guide](https://www.simonmott.co.uk/2012/03/vpn-bonding/) that does VPN bonding in a similar way, but no Windows client PC.

Here is a diagram to better explain what I'd like to do.

[image: https://imgur.com/a/LME91]

I'm looking for helpful information about how I would maybe create two VPN network adapters on Windows and bond/team them virtually without having to have a special LAN switch.

Comment: You would need multiple connections to do what you described you fundamentally changed the image from your link (which indicates the approach doesn't even work today) by getting rid of some vital equipment...